# Retrieve the unique keys (second dimension) of a 2 dimensional dictionary in python?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a a 2d dictionary (named d2_dic). I know how to get the unique keys (It's always unique) of the first dimension by d2_dic.keys(). But how do I get the unique keys of the second dimension?

```
from collections import defaultdict
d2_dic = defaultdict(dict)
d2_dic['1']['a'] = 'Hi'
d2_dic['1']['b'] = 'there'
d2_dic['2']['a'] = '.'
```

To get the unique keys in the first dimension, i just need to do a d2_dic.keys() {o/p = 1,2}
How do I retrieve the unique keys of the second dimension??

I need an o/p of [a,b]

Comment: Downvoter, Why the downvote?

Comment: `{x for d in d2_dic.values() for x in d.keys()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity `d2_dic['1']` is itself a dictionary (same with `d2_dic['2']`). So you can use `d2_dic['1'].keys()` to get the keys for that dictionary. If you want a list of all the possible keys in the second dimension then you could do the following.

```
mykeys = []
for k in d2_dic.keys() :
    mykeys.extend(d2_dic[k].keys())
# this removes duplicates but destroys order
mykeys = list(set(mykeys))
print mykeys # ['a', 'b']
```

Apparently, you can also do this in one line with list comprehension, as per the comment by @vaultah: `mykeys = list({x for d in d2_dic.values() for x in d.keys()})`.

You have to be careful with this though, because `d2_dic['2'][mykeys[1]]` will resault in `KeyError: 'b'`. You may want to wrap some of your code in try and except statements. For example:

```
for i in d2_dic.keys() :
    for j in mykeys :
        try : 
            d2_dic[i][j]
        except KeyError :
            d2_dic[i][j] = None
        print i, j, d2_dic[i][j]
```

Note that these print statements won't work in python 3